# What is the most efficient way to process AJAX requests?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

For example let's say I have a controller called News. Methods of News include Create, Edit, Delete, etc. So let's say for users with javascript enabled, we can use AJAX to deal with these things and use the controllers if not. For example, going to /news we can create news, edit, or delete without leaving this page...with AJAX. Without javascript, we would have to go to /news/create, /news/edit/1, /news/delete/1, etc.

So then what way is more efficient to deal with AJAX requests? On each controller should I just have a conditional to check whether the request was sent with AJAX, something like:

```
if(isset($_POST['ajax'])) {
    // serve ajax request
} else {
    // serve regular request
}
```

Or should I create additional methods such as ajaxCreate, ajaxEdit, ajaxDelete, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never use `/news/delete/1` to delete news!

use `POST /news/delete` and pass a news id

With that said, both ajax request and regular requests should be made to the same URL. the difference is that regular requests will return an html response and an ajax request will return xml/json/etc

Page: `/news/create/`

```
// create new news item code goes here

// most newer javascript libraries set this header so you know the page
// was requested via ajax
if ( isset( $_SERVER['X-Requested-With'] && $_SERVER['X-Requested-With'] == 'XMLHttpRequest' ) {
    //output status code or new news item
    exit;
}

// not an ajax request load a view
require( 'views/news_create.php' );
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks. Also the news/delete/1 would be a confirmation page, with a form button of course.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your AJAX requests be almost the same as your regular requests, except the regular requests have an additional layer (rendering a page) on top?

Your conditional check should simply regulate whether you respond with something like a JSON response, or a full page - in effect, what view you invoke (assuming an MVC-style setup).

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to pull this functionality into an API. For example, I can have a folder structure like the following:

```
web
  - api
      - 1.0
         - news
            create.php
  news.php
```

Then your page is accessible at the 'news.php' URL. Inside this file you consume your own api. The AJAX would also directly access the API at the 'api/1.0/news/create.php' URL for instance.

This leads to less API code in the controllers/views.

Bob

Comment: But what differentiates the AJAX request from a normal request? Different responses are needed. For example a normal request would have a view call which would load the entire page layout, but AJAX only needs a status returned.